# Outbound email not sent when executed from post sandbox refresh script

Tags: sandbox-refresh

System.resetpassword(Id iduser, true) - This method throws exception & the outbound email not sent when executed from post sandbox refresh apex class.

System.UnexpectedException: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: An unexpected error occurred.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As of now, there is no option available in salesforce to programmatically update email deliverability settings. Salesforce support team confirmed the same. Contact Salesforce support team for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you refresh a Sandbox all User email addresses are modified to use an example domain. You have to update the email address to send email.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000193090&language=en_US

Comment: Thanks Saroj! 
During Sandbox refresh, Is it possible to update email deliverability via apex class? so that I can use that apex class to execute after sandbox refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check Email deliverability which is usually reset on Sandbox refresh. Check and make sure it's set to "All email". Refer below link for more details

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=emailadmin_deliverability.htm

Comment: Thanks Anshul! 
During Sandbox refresh, Is it possible to update email deliverability via apex class? so that I can use that apex class to execute after sandbox refresh.

Comment: @Logesh9788: I don't think there is any way to programmaticaly set that value.